# GitHub: How to revert developer branch to Master branch?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Github and am helping out a startup company.  Their main developer had committed lots of test code on developer branch, which is useless for us. (and he left of course)

I literally need to revert the whole developer branch to the current state of master branch.

Would that be possible?

We are also using `deployhq.com` if this is of any use to achieve this.

EDIT: Some more background info.

I am sure the GitHub experts know this, but we use deployhq.com to deploy the code from developer branch into staging and/or production server.  Since the developer branch is useless, I need to revert it back to the current state of the master branch.  Hope it makes more sense.

Comment: if more information is required, please leave a comment. Or even if this is not possble, please leave a comment too. down voting alone doesn't really help me to understand how I can improve the question. Thanks

Comment: I voted down because I think it's something that anyone with basic git knowledge (or with little research) could do. For example, [gitready](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/16/rolling-back-changes-with-revert.html) and [gitref](http://gitref.org/basic/#reset) explain some basic commands that you could easily adapt to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear from your question but I'm guessing you're asking for a way to rewrite history for the `developer` branch, forget all the previous changes in the branch, and make `developer` branch to be at the same commit as the current `master`.

If that be the case you can merely move the branch pointer of `developer` to `master`:

```
# Checkout any other branch than developer, using master as an example
# Any other branch should also work
git checkout master

# Move the branch pointer of developer to the current master
git branch -f developer master

# Push the commits for developer
# **WARNING:** This is going to rewrite history
# Also all commits under the old developer branch will become dangling
git push -f origin developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with a remote repository is always done with `git push`.

You can reset the developer branch to the master branch simply by force pushing:

```
git push -f origin master:developer
```

But if I understood you correctly you just want to get rid of the branch:

```
git push --delete origin developer
```

If you ever need a new developer branch just push a new one:

```
git push origin HEAD:developer
```

Comment: many thanks for your response. Without touching the existing branches, I just did a `git push origin HEAD:developer2` to create a new developer branch. However it did `Merge pull request #715 from project/develop`  instead of master.  Therefore it seems the origin head is pointing to develop instead of master, correct?

Comment: Creating a develop2 branch feels a bit inconvenient but is technically perfectly fine. I don't understand what exactly you did with your pull request. What do you mean by origin head?